# nez dans le sein

Tags: sens, expressions, traduction

What does the expression "nez dans le sein" mean? "The heart of"?

Here's some context (an old French translation of Erasmus's *In Praise of Folly*):

> …ces termes monstrueux qui sont **nez dans le sein** de la subtilité Scolastique…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a typo in the first edition (1728) of Erasmus French translation by Gueudeville:

---

[image]

---

The 1777 edition corrects *nez* to *nés* (and removes *subtilité*):

> …ces termes monstrueux qui sont **nés** dans le sein de la 
>   scolastique…

---

[image]

---